# Sql Server query that returns prices from each shop on each date and adds a 0 if no data is present for the shopId on a particular date

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, chart.js

I have this Sql Server database table called productPrices:

```
 shopId int 
 price  decimal(18, 2)  
 dateFound  datetime
```

I want to make an sql query formatted to use on a chart.js line chart. The line chart takes the following parameters:

An array of X Values - which in this context will be the date/day (from lowest to highest)
Each shopId contains an array of prices.

I have made a codepen version of how the data should be displayed in the line chart (using just data added manually)

https://codepen.io/nickbuus/pen/OJxEGqK

The problem is that if no price was added for the shop on a particular day then a data value for instance 0 still needs to be present since price arrays length has to match the X Values array.

How could I make a query that fills out 0 when the particular shopId doesn't have a value on that particular date?

What is the best way to format the returned data from the sql query when it should be used for the structure that chart.js line chart uses?

Comment: Seems like you want a Calendar Table that you can `CROSS JOIN` to your Shops table, and then you can `LEFT JOIN` to your Prices table. Otherwise you *could* use an inline-tally (don't use an rCTE, they are slow) to create all the dates you need and `CROSS JOIN` *that* to your Shops table.

Comment: You need a source for "all shops" and a source of "all dates" (the calendar already suggested). You cross join the first two and then outer join to your table. No idea what your X values correspond to in your chart - was that intended to be dates?

Comment: But I have already the one table - I cannot create any other tables.

Comment: *"I cannot create any other tables."* Then you're going to need to use a tally to create your calendar inline, and then `CROSS JOIN` it to a `DISTINCT` dataset of your `shopId`s. I would, however, suggest you expand your design so that you have a `Shop` table; you clearly need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally what you should be doing here is creating a Calendar Table. I'm not going to cover how you create a calendar table here, as a search in your favourite search engine of something like "Calendar Table SQL Server" will give you a huge wealth of resources and give some great explanations and their use cases.

Once you have a `Calendar` table, you need to `CROSS JOIN` that to your `Shops` table; which I also *assume* you have. Then you can simply `LEFT JOIN` to your `Prices` table.

So a parametrised query might look like this:

```sql
SELECT S.ShopID,
       COUNT(P.Price) AS Prices,
       C.CalendarDate AS Datefound
FROM dbo.Calendar C
     CROSS JOIN dbo.Shops S
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Prices P ON C.CalendarDate = P.DateFound --Though DateFound is a datetime, I assume it's time portion is 00:00:00.000
                           AND S.ShopId = P.ShopID
WHERE C.CalendarDate >= @StartDate
  AND C.CalendarDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
GROUP BY S.ShopID,
         C.CalendarDate;
```

If you can't, for some reason, create a Calendar table and you don't have (and can't create) a Shop table (I strongly suggest you do create one though) then you'll need to use an inline tally to create your Calendar, and `DISTINCT` to get the Shop IDs.

A parametrised query would look something like this:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1,000 rows. Add more cross joins for more rows
Calendar AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate) AS CalendarDate
    FROM Tally T),
Shops AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT P.ShopID
    FROM dbo.Prices P)
SELECT S.ShopID,
       COUNT(P.Price) AS Prices,
       C.CalendarDate AS Datefound
FROM dbo.Calendar C
     CROSS JOIN dbo.Shops S
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Prices P ON C.CalendarDate = P.DateFound --Though DateFound is a datetime, I assume it's time portion is 00:00:00.000
                           AND S.ShopId = P.ShopID
GROUP BY S.ShopID,
         C.CalendarDate;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c5e9d6e3e79a7a253e5c935e4bf4705c)

Comment: Hi @Larnu. Thx. I have created a Calendar/Shop table:
SELECT S.ShopID,
       COUNT(P.Price) AS ProductPrices,
       C.CalendarDate AS Datefound
FROM dbo.Calendar C
     CROSS JOIN dbo.Shop S
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductPrices P ON C.CalendarDate = P.DateFound 
                           AND S.ShopId = 
         S.ShopID
WHERE C.CalendarDate >= @@StartDate
  AND C.CalendarDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @@EndDate);
I am getting this error: 'dbo.Shop.ShopId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: also is this correct:
  AND S.ShopId = S.ShopID ?

Comment: Incorrect alias, apologies, @NickDeveloper . As for the error, that's because I forgot my `GROUP BY`. Also added. A query is impossible to test when you don't supply sample data.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu - I chose your solution no #1. The only problem is that if there is no price on a certain date from a shop then your solution doesn't return any results from this shop at all on that date when it should return a 0 in the price field. Do you know how I could solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NickDeveloper, no it will return a result, that's exactly what the `Calendar` table is there for. A row for *every* date between the date range for every shop will be returned .

Comment: Hi again @Larnu - I cannot get it to work. I have created an sqlfiddle for it to test - perhaps you can take a look at it. It is here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1fc8bc/2/0 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for supplying sample data with DML and DDL. Apart from a couple of broken aliases, I can't actually replicate the problem. Perhaps the SQL Fiddle is wrong, @NickDeveloper. I have added a fiddle to my answer, which does work,

Comment: I would suggest that the SQL Fiddle site you're using is flawed, @NickDeveloper. I just tried running the queries there and it complains that the variables aren't declared, when they are. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f0f2a0/3)

Comment: Hi again @Larnu - in order to fix the problem with SqlFiddle you have to select GO in the last dropdown on the right side. It runs now: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f0f2a0/4

Comment: Hi again @Larnu :-) the issue I am seeing is because I only want the results from a specific productid from the prices table. You can see it here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9617c/3
if I include an AND P.ProductId = 7 then it fails to include equal number of rows per date. it only works if it returns all of the results from the Prices table at the moment.

Comment: Where are you putting `AND AND P.ProductId = 7` @NickDeveloper ? It *should* be in the `ON`. If you've put it in the `WHERE` you're turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an` INNER JOIN` and completely negating the whole point of the Calendar and Shops tables.

Comment: It's counting the prices, as that's what I assumed you wanted, @NickDeveloper .

Comment: I can see that can be fixed by using MAX instead of COUNT. Is that correct?

Comment: You likely don't need aggregation, @NickDeveloper .

Comment: You mean just remove the group by, @Larnu ?

Comment: And the `COUNT` (obviously).